# Show multiple infowindow at once in gMap

Tags: javascript, jquery-gmap

From the author's website, let's say we have multiple markers:

```
$("#map1").gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: 47.660937,
                              longitude: 9.569803,
                              html: "Tettnang, Germany",
                              popup: true }],
                  zoom: 6 });

$("#map2").gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: 47.660940,
                              longitude: 9.569803,
                              html: "Tettnang, Germany",
                              popup: true }],
                  zoom: 6 });
$("#map3").gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: 47.660946,
                          longitude: 9.569803,
                          html: "Tettnang, Germany",
                          popup: true }],
              zoom: 6 });
```

We use `popup: true` to show the infowindow by default when the map is loaded. But only the last infowindow (#map3) is shown. Others remain just a marker.

How do I make all infowindow to popup at once? Thanks.

Comment: why not use Google Map V3 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed on the [Google Map API page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Info_Windows), only one InfoWindow may be displayed at one time (at least with V2)

Best alternative I've found so far is [this library called elabel.js](http://sub1.econym.org.uk/gmap/elabel.htm) which can be used to add labels to the map